# MySQL Comma separated tables for Joining

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, itemID, ordercount
FROM (
  SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) AS ordercount
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY itemID
  ORDER BY ordercount DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

Like I know what it's doing, it generates a set of records with three columns `rank`, `itemID`, `ordercount`, where rank holds the index of the current row.

What is then the reason of JOINING t1 with (SELECT @rn:=0)? Because if I remove that table "t2" it does the same thing except the variable `rn` will not get restored. How does (SELECT @rn:=0) t2 restores the variable `rn`?

I know what the query is doing, what I dont know is just the last , (SELECT @rn:=0)t2 table.

Because, ideally if we let t1 and t2 be two tables, then doing  SELECT * FROM t1, t2; will generate a table with joined rows. But how is it acting in the aforementioned example?

Comment: `@rn := 0` is a variable assignment. Joining with it causes it to be executed at the beginning of the query. Otherwise you'd need to do `SET @rn = 0;` before the query to reset the variable.

Comment: So the assignment gets executed only once and not for every row of t1?

Comment: Correct. When you join with a subquery, the subquery is just executed once.

Comment: Ok so why isn't the column @rn:=0 showing up in the resultant set? Because usually when joining you get column names from table t1 and t2. Is it because of how JOIN works?

Comment: Because it wasn't given an alias in the subquery, and even if it were, you didn't select it in the main query's `SELECT` list.

Comment: So if it were to show up, it would always hold the value 0 for every row?

Comment: Yes. If you want to see this, change the subquery to `(SELECT @rn:= 0 initrn)` and add `initrn` to the first `SELECT` list.

Comment: Yes I just did that after I asked that question and yeah I got 0 for every row under its column (that I've named 'initial'). So thank you so much that helped me a lot.

Comment: The query is incorrect. ORDER BY applied in subquery can be ignored in outer query. You must move it to outer query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, itemID, ordercount
FROM (
    SELECT itemID, COUNT(*) AS ordercount
    FROM orders
    WHERE (@rn:=0)=0
    GROUP BY itemID
    ) t1
ORDER BY ordercount DESC;
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't ideal. Can you explain what this code does and why it addresses the OP's problem?

Comment: @AndrewRay Placing the initialization of variables in the WHERE clause is a common way to get rid of the initializing subquery. The evaluation of constant expressions in WHERE is the very first stage of one-table query execution.

Comment: You should add your explanation to the answer by editing it. Comments are easily lost.